# Expanding and collapsing drop-down menus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a navigation menu which contains some menu items (Home, About Us, Admission...). Using the placeholder by the right, I was able to successfully open and close the 'About Us' drop-down menu. The question is, how can I achieve the same thing with other menu items (specifically, the 'Admission' drop-down menu) without having to assign specific id to each and every menu-item? Also, how can I close the navigation menu when an external environment is clicked?

```js
document.getElementById("showSubMenu").addEventListener("click", openSubMenu);

function openSubMenu() {
  let subMenuBar = document.getElementById("subMenu-Items");
  subMenuBar.style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("showSubMenu").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("hideSubMenu").style.display = "inline";
}

document.getElementById("hideSubMenu").addEventListener("click", closeSubMenu);

function closeSubMenu() {
  let subMenuBar = document.getElementById("subMenu-Items");
  subMenuBar.style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("showSubMenu").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("hideSubMenu").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* margin: 0; */
  padding: 0;
}


/* NAVIGATION MENU BAR */

.navMenu-Container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(15, 14, 18);
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px 10px 25px 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
  width: fit-content;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px 0px white;
}

.searchBox {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.searchArrow {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.searchArrow img {
  width: 26px;
  height: 22px;
}

.searchArrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navMenu {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li:first-child {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:link {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  width: 80%;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:visited,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:hover,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: navy;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:active,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: navy;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.showSubMenu,
.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.showSubMenu img,
.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu img {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu {
  display: none;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.showSubMenu:hover,
.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: navy;
}

.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:link {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  width: 80%;
}

.navMenu .subMenu-Items {
  display: none;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

```html
<!-- NAVIGATION MENU -->
<div id="navMenu-Container" class="navMenu-Container">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="searchArrow"><img src="Icons/Arrow (Right).png" alt="Go" /></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="navMenu">
    <ul class="menuItems">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="aboutus" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        <span id="showSubMenu" class="showSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <span id="hideSubMenu" class="hideSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <ul id="subMenu-Items" class="subMenu-Items">
          <li><a href="">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Our Community</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Achievements</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Vision, Mission & Core Values</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Head Teacher's Note</a></li>
          <li><a href="">School Songs & Prayer</a></li>
          <li><a href="">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="admissions" href="admissions.html">Admissions</a>
        <span id="showSubMenu" class="showSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <span id="hideSubMenu" class="hideSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <ul id="subMenu-Items" class="subMenu-Items">
          <li><a href="">Why BGS?</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Admission Process</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Entrance Examination</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="academics" href="academics.html">Academics</a></li>
      <li><a class="gallery" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a class="alumni" href="events.html">Events</a></li>
      <li><a class="contactus" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="login" href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Also note that there is an error in the Developer Console. `document.getElementById("preTopNav")` doesn't exist, and therefor the code breaks. This should be the first place to look at when your JavaScript code isn't working.

Comment: @Daan I've removed the non-existing function. It is actually part of the complete code from which I excerpted this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted had a lot unnecessary content irrelevant to your question.

So here is a smaller snippet that does what you required.

What you need to do is provide a target for each menu toggle. Add event listeners to those toggles and pull the associated target using javascript.

Instead of showing and hiding elements using javascript, you're better off using css for this. That way you can add and remove classes that tells you whether your menu is open or not. I've used 'menu-open' in this case.

```js
var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');
// console.log(toggles);
toggles.forEach(
    (toggle) => {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
          const id = toggle.getAttribute('data-target');
          const menu = document.getElementById(id);
          menu.classList.toggle('menu-open');          
        })
    }
)
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* margin: 0; */
  padding: 0;
}

.navMenu {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items > li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li:first-child {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li > a:link {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  width: 80%;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li > a:visited,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items > li > a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li > a:hover,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items > li > a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: navy;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li > a:active,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items > li > a:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: navy;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li .showSubMenu,
.navMenu .menuItems > li .hideSubMenu {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li > .showSubMenu img,
.navMenu .menuItems > li > .hideSubMenu img {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li .hideSubMenu {
  display: none;
}

.navMenu .menuItems > li .showSubMenu:hover,
.navMenu .menuItems > li .hideSubMenu:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: navy;
}

.navMenu .subMenu-Items li > a:link {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  width: 80%;
}

.navMenu .subMenu-Items {
  display: none;
}
.navMenu .menu-open .subMenu-Items {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navMenu">
  <ul class="menuItems">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="sub-1">
      <a class="aboutus" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
      <span class="toggle" data-target="sub-1">
        <span id="showSubMenu" class="showSubMenu">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" />
        </span>
        <span id="hideSubMenu" class="hideSubMenu">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" />
        </span>
      </span>
      <ul id="subMenu-Items" class="subMenu-Items">
        <li><a href="">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Our Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Achievements</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vision, Mission & Core Values</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Head Teacher's Note</a></li>
        <li><a href="">School Songs & Prayer</a></li>
        <li><a href="">FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="sub-2">
      <a class="admissions" href="admissions.html">Admissions</a>
      <span class="toggle" data-target="sub-2">
        <span id="showSubMenu" class="showSubMenu">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" />
        </span>
        <span id="hideSubMenu" class="hideSubMenu">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" />
        </span>
      </span>
      <ul id="subMenu-Items" class="subMenu-Items">
        <li><a href="">Why BGS?</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Admission Process</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Entrance Examination</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="academics" href="academics.html">Academics</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. `The code you posted had a lot unnecessary content irrelevant to your question.` Concerning this statement, you're absolutely. I was carelessly in a hurry. Will be more careful next time.

Comment: Please, how can I code the menu bar to display as none when an outside area is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Merged two clicks in a single and handled them generically on the base of classes and now if you will put these classes on more elements, you need to register any new click events. Hope it helps.

```js
 document.getElementById("trigram").addEventListener("click", openNavMenu);

function openNavMenu() {
  let navMenuBar = document.getElementById("navMenu-Container");
  navMenuBar.style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("trigram").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("preTopNav").style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", closeNavMenu);

function closeNavMenu() {
  let navMenuBar = document.getElementById("navMenu-Container");
  navMenuBar.style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("trigram").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("preTopNav").style.display = "flex";
}

// I have merged both event 'hideSubMenu' and 'openSubMenu' into single event and showed hide menu on the base of the class on the target and now it will work on any element with these classes no need to register new click events.

document.getElementById("mainMenu").addEventListener("click", toggleSubMenu);

function toggleSubMenu(event) {
 if(event.target.classList.contains('showSubMenu')) {
    let subMenuBar = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("subMenu-Items");
    for(let i=0; i<subMenuBar.length; i++) {
      subMenuBar[i].style.display = "block";
    }

    event.target.parentNode.querySelector("#showSubMenu").style.display = "none";
    event.target.parentNode.querySelector("#hideSubMenu").style.display = "inline";
   } else if(event.target.classList.contains('hideSubMenu')) {
      let subMenuBar = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("subMenu-Items");
    
    for(let i=0; i<subMenuBar.length; i++) {
      subMenuBar[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    event.target.parentNode.querySelector("#showSubMenu").style.display = "inline";
    event.target.parentNode.querySelector("#hideSubMenu").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* margin: 0; */
  padding: 0;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.67%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.67%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.67%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
  width: 91.67%;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.navBar-Container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.schoolBatch {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.schoolTitle {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.schoolName {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.schoolMotto {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto 0;
}

.schoolLogo {
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}


/* Clicking the trigram */

.navBarTrigram img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
}

.navBarTrigram {
  width: fit-content;
}

.navBarTrigram:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navBarTrigram .close {
  display: none;
}


/* NAVIGATION MENU BAR */

.navMenu-Container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(15, 14, 18);
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px 10px 25px 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
  width: fit-content;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px 0px white;
}

.searchBox {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.searchArrow {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.searchArrow img {
  width: 26px;
  height: 22px;
}

.searchArrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navMenu {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li:first-child {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(41, 35, 35);
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:link {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  width: 80%;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:visited,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:hover,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: navy;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>a:active,
.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: navy;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.showSubMenu,
.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.showSubMenu img,
.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu img {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu {
  display: none;
}

.navMenu .menuItems>li>.showSubMenu:hover,
.navMenu .menuItems>li>.hideSubMenu:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: navy;
}

.navMenu .subMenu-Items>li>a:link {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  width: 80%;
}

.navMenu .subMenu-Items {
  display: none;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

```html
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
<div class="navBar-Container">
  <div class="schoolBatch col-10">
    <div class="schoolLogo-Container"><img src="Icons/bethellogo.png" class="schoolLogo" alt="BGS Logo" /></div>
    <div class="schoolTitle">
      <div class="schoolName">BETHEL GEMINI SCHOOLS</div>
      <div class="schoolMotto">Heaven's Light, Our Ground</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navBarTrigram col-2">
    <img id="trigram" class="trigram" src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="trigram" />
    <img id="close" class="close" src="Icons/close.png" alt="close" />
  </div>
</div>

<!-- NAVIGATION MENU -->
<div id="navMenu-Container" class="navMenu-Container">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="searchArrow"><img src="Icons/Arrow (Right).png" alt="Go" /></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="navMenu">
    <ul id="mainMenu" class="menuItems">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="aboutus" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        <span id="showSubMenu" class="showSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <span id="hideSubMenu" class="hideSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <ul id="subMenu-Items" class="subMenu-Items">
          <li><a href="">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Our Community</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Achievements</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Vision, Mission & Core Values</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Head Teacher's Note</a></li>
          <li><a href="">School Songs & Prayer</a></li>
          <li><a href="">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="admissions" href="admissions.html">Admissions</a>
        <span id="showSubMenu" class="showSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <span id="hideSubMenu" class="hideSubMenu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20/" alt="" /></span>
        <ul id="subMenu-Items" class="subMenu-Items">
          <li><a href="">Why BGS?</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Admission Process</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Entrance Examination</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="academics" href="academics.html">Academics</a></li>
      <li><a class="gallery" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a class="alumni" href="events.html">Events</a></li>
      <li><a class="contactus" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="login" href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```